# PrimeNG Schedule load events for current date range

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I've managed to get PrimeNG Schedule working in an Angular2 project when loading my events using onInit(), however I really want to be loading the events based on FullCalendar's current date range. I'm assuming that I should load my events using viewRender, however I can't seem to get the parameters that this should pass sent through to my function.

My directive is setup using:

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" (viewRender)="fetchEvents($view, $element)"></p-schedule>
```

And the fetchEvents function is currently just trying to output the parameters:

```
public fetchEvents(view, element){
console.log("fetchEvents:", view, element);
```

}

However when looking at the console, it simply says that both view and element are undefined. I'm sure this will be to do with how the view and element are passed through, and I've used taken the same syntax as the onEventClick example on the PrimeNG site, but this clearly isn't working. Any ideas on how they should be passed through, or anything else I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
<p-schedule (viewRender)="fetchEvents($event)" ...></p-schedule>
```

And in your component:

```
fetchEvents(eventData) {
  console.log("fetchEvents:", eventData.view, eventData.element);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be right, whilst the $event object is passed through, there is new view or element property to it. The documentation for fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ says that view and element shoul dbe passed through.

Comment: See also at this line from primeng source https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/schedule/schedule.ts#L227

Comment: `The events payload can be accessed by the parameter $event on the components output event handler:` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

Comment: I had tested it, yes however I must've got something wrong as retesting it today I get the result you've described, so this is now working! Thanks!